# Is there a Group BY function for finding result with elastic search query?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I have tried to integrate group by with elastic search. But I didn't get the answer properly. Please support me to fix this issue. Indexed data is,

```
data = [
       { "fruit":"apple", "taste":5, "timestamp":100},
       { "fruit":"pear", "taste":5, "timestamp":110},
       { "fruit":"apple", "taste":4, "timestamp":200},
       { "fruit":"pear", "taste":8, "timestamp":90},
       { "fruit":"banana", "taste":5, "timestamp":100}]`
My query is, 
`myQuery = {"query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "aggs": {
      "group_by_fruit": {
        "terms": {
          "field": "fruit.keyword"
        },
      }
    }
    }
```

It showing all 5 data in the output. Actually I nee d to get only 3 records. The expected result is,

```
[
   { "fruit":"apple", "taste":4, "timestamp":200},
   { "fruit":"pear", "taste":8, "timestamp":90},
   { "fruit":"banana", "taste":5, "timestamp":100}]
```

Comment: Do you expect the final output to be sorted by `taste` or `timestamp`? The expected answer you've mentioned in the question shows `max timestamp` for `apple` but `min timestamp` for `pear`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the documents with **distinct** fruit fields having the largest **timestamp** value you should use a [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation.

```
{
    "query": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "top_tags": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "fruit.keyword",
                "size": <MAX_NUMBER_OF_DISTINCT_FRUITS>
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_by_fruit": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "timestamp": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As you have mentioned I have tried with "size": 0, return empty result. I have changed page size to 10, like, "size": 10, this returning all the five rows. :-( didn't meet my requirement.

Comment: Settings size to 0 only allow to remove the **hits** field which contains the documents match by your query (in your case, ALL the documents). What you expect is in the **aggregations** field of the response.

Comment: I am expecting result like this, [
   { "fruit":"apple", "taste":4, "timestamp":200},
   { "fruit":"pear", "taste":8, "timestamp":90},
   { "fruit":"banana", "taste":5, "timestamp":100}]
ie, array with  distinct fruit name

Comment: If you want  the response from elasticsearch formated **exactly** like this, then it will not work. If you can rewrite the response, then you have what you want in the fields `group_by_fruit.hits.hits._source` of the array `aggregations.top_tags.buckets`.

Comment: You are looking at the response of the query from elasticsearch, not the aggregation. In SQL, using a **GROUP BY** you will get only the grouped results. Using elasticsearch and aggregation, you have **both** the result of the select **without** aggregation in the **hits** field (equivalent to result of a SELECT without GROUP BY) **and** the results of the aggregations (equivalent of the GROUP BY) in the **aggregation** field.

Comment: I am not expecting formatted result. But now I am getting total values 5 as result, like this, total: { value: 5, relation: 'eq' } Actually, after implementing group by with fruits name , it will need to return only 3 records. Hope , you get my question.